# Cummulative sum of variable by a condition and ID on sas

Tags: sas, sum

I am trying to sum one variable as long as another remains constant. I want to cumulative sum dur as long as a is constant. when a changes the sum restarts. when a new id, the sum restarts.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p9aD.png)

and I would like to do this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30ega.png)

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please post relevant parts of your question as text, not as images, as that makes it easier for us to help.

Comment: In this case, you may want to explain why `proc freq` does not meet your needs.  That is the default tool for calculating cumulative sums in SAS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BY` statement to specify the variables whose different value combinations organize data rows into groups.  You are resetting an accumulated value at the start of each group and adding to the accumulator at each row in the group.  Use `retain` to maintain a new variables value between the DATA step implicit loop iterations.  The SUM statement is a unique SAS feature for accumulating and retaining.

Example:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id a;
  if first.a then mysum = 0;
  mysum + dur;
run;
```

The `SUM` statement is different than the `SUM` function.

```
<variable> + <expression>;  * SUM statement, unique to SAS (not found in other languages);
```

can be thought of as

```
retain <variable>;
<variable> = sum (<variable>, <expression>);
```

Comment: Not sure how unique the sum statement is. See this syntax in C  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/c-compound-assignment?view=msvc-160   But the RETAIN is unique.  Or more accurately the clearing of variables before each iteration that makes RETAIN needed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned, you need to self-join your table with a ranked column.

It should be ranked by `id` and `a` columns.

`FROM WORK.QUERY_FOR_STCKOVRFLW t1;` is the table you provided in the screenshot

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_STCKOVRFLW_0001 AS 
   SELECT t1.id, 
          t1.a, 
          t1.dur, 
          /* mono */
            (monotonic()) AS mono
      FROM WORK.QUERY_FOR_STCKOVRFLW t1;
QUIT;

PROC SORT
    DATA=WORK.QUERY_FOR_STCKOVRFLW_0001
    OUT=WORK.SORTTempTableSorted
    ;
    BY id a;
RUN;
PROC RANK DATA = WORK.SORTTempTableSorted
    TIES=MEAN
    OUT=WORK.RANKRanked(LABEL="Rank Analysis for WORK.QUERY_FOR_STCKOVRFLW_0001");
    BY id a;
    VAR mono;
RANKS rank_mono ;
RUN; QUIT;



PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_RANKRANKED AS 
   SELECT t1.id, 
          t1.a, 
          t1.dur, 
          /* SUM_of_dur */
            (SUM(t2.dur)) FORMAT=BEST12. AS SUM_of_dur
      FROM WORK.RANKRANKED t1
           LEFT JOIN WORK.RANKRANKED t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id) AND (t1.a = t2.a AND (t1.rank_mono  >=  t2.rank_mono ))
      GROUP BY t1.id,
               t1.a,
               t1.dur;
QUIT;
```